# How to split the date to half yearly from given date?

Tags: jquery, date, textbox

For Example,

```
First Half --- 01 Jun 2015 to 30 Nov 2015
Second Half --- 01 Dec 2015 to 31 May 2016
```

Given two date from Textbox.

```
From Date --- 01 Nov 2015
To Date --- 15 Feb 2016
```

Here split the given date based on `First half` and `Second half`.

Expected Output is :

```
First Half --- From Date : 01 Nov 2015 and To Date : 30 Nov 2015
Second half --- From Date : 01 Dec 2015 and To Date 15 Feb 2016
```

Comment: What language? JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for calculating the first half, without using any libraries. I think you should be able to figure out the rest for the second half:

```
var currDate = new Date();
var tmp = new Date(currDate.getTime());
var lowerFirstHalf = new Date(tmp.setMonth(currDate.getMonth()-6));

lowerFirstHalf = new Date(lowerFirstHalf.getFullYear(),lowerFirstHalf.getMonth(),1);

tmp = new Date(lowerFirstHalf.getTime());
var upperFirstHalf = new Date(tmp.setMonth(tmp.getMonth()+6));

upperFirstHalf = new Date(upperFirstHalf.getFullYear(),upperFirstHalf.getMonth()+1,0);

console.log("Current date: "+currDate);
console.log("Lower First half: "+lowerFirstHalf);
console.log("Upper First half: "+upperFirstHalf);
```

Result:

```
Current date: Sat Jan 30 2016 08:38:11 GMT+0100 (CET) _display:56:1
Lower First half: Wed Jul 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST) _display:57:1
Upper First half: Sun Jan 31 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET) _display:58:1
```

Or check out this jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8w8v9/973/

Answer (score 0):

```
       function FormatDate(inputdate) {
          var date = inputdate.getDate();
          var month = inputdate.getMonth() + 1;
          var year = inputdate.getFullYear();
          return date + '/' + month + '/' + year;
       }

        function HalfYearlyDate() {
        var firstHalfstart = new Date("01 Jun 2015") //First half start date
        var firstHalfend = new Date("30 Nov 2015") // First half end date

        var secondHalfStart = new Date("01 Dec 2015")//second half start date
        var secondHalfEnd = new Date("31 May 2016")// second half end date

        var date1 = new Date("01 Nov 2015"); // input first half date
        var date2 = new Date("15 Feb 2016"); // // input second half date

        //Please format the date using a custom function or using moment.js before printing
        if (date1.getTime() >= firstHalfstart.getTime() && date1.getTime() <= firstHalfend.getTime()) {

            if (date1.getTime() <= date2.getTime()) {
                console.log("First Half --- From Date : " + FormatDate(date1) + " and To Date :" + FormatDate(date2));
            }
            else {
                console.log("First Half --- From Date : " + FormatDate(date1) + " and To Date :" + FormatDate(firstHalfend));
            }
        }
        else {
            console.log("some error message");
        }

        if (date2.getTime() >= secondHalfStart.getTime() && date2.getTime() <= secondHalfEnd.getTime()) {

            if (date2.getTime() <= secondHalfEnd.getTime()) {
                console.log("Second  Half --- From Date : " + FormatDate(secondHalfStart) + " and To Date :" + FormatDate(date2));
            }
            else {
                console.log("Second  Half --- From Date : " + FormatDate(secondHalfStart) + " and To Date :" + FormatDate(secondHalfEnd));
            }
        }
        else {
            console.log("some error message");
        }    
   }
```

Hope above code will give you insight to solve the issue

Comment: suppose i given from date : 01 jun 2015 and to date : 20 nov 2015.              My Expected output is first half from date : 01 jun 2015 and to date : 20 nov 2015  ... Second Half from date : null and to date : null

Comment: Can you use && and operator instaed of || or.Okay I will update the answer.I got your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Its Worked Perfectly

```
// Check Text box From & To Date between First Half
        if (firstHalfFrom >= txtFromDate || txtFromDate <= firstHalfTo) {
            firstHalfFromDate = MyDateFormatter(new Date(txtFromDate));      // First Half From Date
            if (firstHalfTo >= txtToDate || txtToDate <= firstHalfFrom) {     // First Half To Date
                firstHalfToDate = MyDateFormatter(new Date(txtToDate));
            } else {
                firstHalfToDate = MyDateFormatter(new Date(firstHalfTo));
            }
        } else {
            firstHalfFromDate = "";
            firstHalfToDate = "";
        }

        // Check Text box From & To Date between Second Half
        if (secondHalfTo <= txtToDate || txtToDate >= secondHalfFrom) {
            secondHalfToDate = MyDateFormatter(new Date(txtToDate));      // Second Half To Date
            if (secondHalfFrom <= txtFromDate || txtFromDate >= secondHalfTo) {     // Second Half From Date 
                secondHalfFromDate = MyDateFormatter(new Date(txtFromDate));          
            } else {
                secondHalfFromDate = MyDateFormatter(new Date(secondHalfFrom));
            }
        } else {
            secondHalfFromDate = "";
            secondHalfToDate = "";
        }
```